# Is there any open source of NFT Marketplace using 0x Protocol?

Tags: nft, 0x

I have worked on several NFT Marketplaces using Solidity before.

Now I am going to build MVP NFT Marketplace using 0x protocal.
Can you help me how to find the open source (with document hopefully) for that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://reservoir.tools/, they have an open source marketplace and aggregated APIs including 0x.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment at my knowledge there is no open source nft marketplace using 0x v4. I and my team are building one with support from ZRX DAO, I will be posting here later when available.

For using the old 0x contracts you have this deprecated one built at time by 0x team: https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit

If you need just a sdk you can check this one: https://docs.swapsdk.xyz/readme/swap-nft-less-than-greater-than-erc-20-example